# SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file electronjs

Tags: javascript, electron

I am facing the sqlite db issue in production mode.
Its working fine on using npm start (on normally run) but not working when i try to create release file for linux using electron-builder build --linux

my package.json file is as follows

```
  {
    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "test",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron .",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
    },
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "devDependencies": {
   "electron": "^13.1.0",
   "electron-packager": "^15.2.0"
   },
  "build": {
  "appId": "pkg.dmo.com",
  "productName": "sample",
  "copyright": "Copyright",
  "mac": {
   "target": [
    "zip"
   ],
   "publish": [
    "github"
   ]
  },
  "win": {
  "target": [
    "nsis"
   ]
  },
  "linux": {
  "target": [
    "AppImage",
    "tar.gz"
  ]
  },
  "dmg": {
  "icon": "build/icon.icns"
  }
  },
  "dependencies": {
   "jquery": "^3.6.0",
   "sqlite3": "^5.0.2"
   }
   }
```

and my sqlite code is as follows:

```
  let $ = (jQuery = require("jquery"));
  const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();

  const path = require('path')
  const dbPath = path.join(__dirname, 'testdb.db');

  $( document ).ready(function() {  
  let db = new sqlite3.Database(
   dbPath,
    sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE,
    (err) => {
     if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
     }
     }
    );

    db.each("SELECT * FROM Mouse", [], function (err, row) {
    console.log("helli");
    if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return console.error(err.message);
    }

    console.log("mouse row is =>", row);
   });

   });
```

i have tried

```
    var db = new sqlite3.Database( path.resolve(__dirname, 'testdb.db') );
```

and

```
    var db = new sqlite3.Database( path.join(__dirname, 
    'testdb.db').replace('/app.asar', '') );
```

still getting same error in exe but working on local(when npm start)

Comment: Try using a different path for the DB file, `app.getAppPath()` for example or `app.getPath('userData')`